# Calculate function's fixed point in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I want to write sql query that will calculate [iterated function sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_iteration) of some function until it reaches fixed point, and then return that fixed point:

```
f(f(f(f ..(x)))) = x0 = f(x0)
```

E.g. let `f(x) = (256/x + x)/2`:

```
create function f(x float) returns float as $$
  select (256/x + x) / 2
$$ language sql;
```

Here is my attempt to write the query:

```
create function f_sequence(x float) returns table(x0 float) as $$
  with recursive
    t(a,b) as
      (select x, f(x)
        union all
        select b, f(b) from t where a <> b)
    select a from t;
$$ language sql;
```

Now it is possible to get iterated sequence that converges to some fixed point:

```
=# select f_sequence(333);
   f_sequence
------------------
              333
 166.884384384384
 84.2091902577822
 43.6246192451207
 24.7464326525125
 17.5456790321891
 16.0680829640781
 16.0001442390486
 16.0000000006501
               16
(10 rows)
```

(Actually it converges to √256 because this is [Babylonian method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_method#Babylonian_method) of calculating square roots.)

Now I need one additional query to get only the last row from the sequence:

```
=# with
    res as (select array_agg(f_sequence) as res from f_sequence(333))
    select res[array_length(res,1)] from res;
 res 
-----
  16
(1 row)
```

**The question is**: how to write this more concise?
In particular, I don't like that separate query to get the last value (and that I need to accumulate all intermediate values in array).

Comment: As an aside : do you make that for fun or is there a serious reason to use pg here ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a good use of SQL to me.

Comment: This is part of some real problem. I need to recursively build subset of objects. On each step I select best object to be appended to the set until it is not possible to add more.

Comment: FYI you're computing the square root of 128, not 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the definition of f as it is.

In your sequence generation, retain the value of f(x) in the output.

```
create function f_sequence(x float) returns table(x0 float, fx float) as $$
  with recursive
    t(a,b) as
      (select x, f(x)
        union all
        select b, f(b) from t where a <> b)
    select a, b from t;
$$ language sql;
```

Then limit your result to just the fixed value.

```
select x0 from f_sequence(256) where x0 = fx;
```

Edit: Add a procedural version.

```
create function iterf(x float) returns float as $$
declare fx float := f(x);
begin
  while fx != x loop
    x := fx;
    fx := f(x);
  end loop;
  return fx;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Very nice. But it still requires to preserve whole sequence of intermediate values until result is given. In my case I expect ~10k iterations, so it's not a big problem but just out of curiosity, is it possible to do this in constant memory?

Comment: The only way I could think of is to switch to procedural sql and loop. But if you're going to go that approach you might as well do it in the application layer as others have suggested. I added a sample of how you could do that in constant memory to the answer.

Comment: Yep, thank you. That was obvious but I'm little bit to much into recursion.

Comment: Btw, one argument for plsql (vs. application layer) is single query to  DB vs. ~10k.

Comment: If your function is stuck in the DB then yes - you could wind up sending it 10k queries, but I think the assumption was that you'd be able to represent your function in application code and never even bother hitting the database. Also, while recursion might be what you're working on now, don't let that be your only tool. Other languages come equipped for problems like these, e.g. Mathematica's FixedPoint and more general NestWhile, but pure sql makes it a pain. Keep in mind that you could write a recursive plpgsql function, but at 10k iterations you'll likely exceed the stack depth limit.

Comment: "at 10k iterations you'll likely exceed the stack depth limit" -- good point, thanks again.